# How can i solve this incorrect syntax problem?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am making an app for product list. It is running but there is an error when I try to update or delete some cell. I can add new product but i can not delete or update. 
the error is

> Topic: 'Incorect syntax near')'.'
>   it seems near command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: http://hizliresim.com/vNk1TY
http://hizliresim.com/9Hojlh
http://hizliresim.com/OvbBpN
http://hizliresim.com/m7rJ9X
http://hizliresim.com/JjhDBo
http://hizliresim.com/OAFYQn

Comment: there is my codes and mistakes pics.

Comment: Do not post images of code. Include the actual code in the question

Comment: Are you trying to connect to "SQL Server" or MySQL?  The are two different types of databases.  You cannot use the library SQLClient (it is for SQL Server) for MySQL.

Comment: Thank you! I solved my problem. I forgat to delete parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

In this screenshot, you have a little typo - https://i.hizliresim.com/JjhDBo.jpg - remove the **)** after **@Id** in your SQL command, and you should be good to go!

Also in future, would you please add the code you think has the error, in-line with your message - would make it much easier for someone else to assist you, rather than having to open up all the screenshot links you've posted and read through them :)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was going to cry :) It is working now.